# "Translating" one value $- \infty$ to $+ \infty$ to another ($+ \infty$ to $ \gt 0$)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Well even if I need to use the following in a computer game this is a math question. I have a world map which I can scroll with a scroll velocity $(f(x))$ with my mouse. And I have a zoom factor $(x)$ which is $0$ in its initial state and can be positive infinite and negative infinite.

So I'm searching for a function where:

- $x$ can range from $- \infty$ to $+ \infty$
- $f(x)$ should be $\gt 0$
- $f(x)$ should tend to $0$ for $x$ tending to $+ \infty$
- $f(x)$ should tend to $+ \infty$ for $x$ tending to $- \infty$

I bet the solution is somewhat so obviously easy I'm just to blind to see in the moment.

Comment: Try $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

Comment: I deleted my last not so wise comment since your answer works perfectly well and looks awsome due to the exponential thing. I would love to accept your answer if it were one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By request, try $f(x)=e^{-x}$.  As @Andy points out, there are variations and tweaks one can make to the curve, such as $f(x)=e^{-Ax+B}$, where $A>0$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}$, which will give it different shape and move it around.

Answer (score 0):

Any function in the form $f(x)=a^{-x}$ where $a>1$ will satisfy your four conditions.

The closer $a$ is to 1, the more slowly $f(x)$ will approach its asymptotes.